# How to get all data of column in datatables when using ajax

Tags: ajax, datatable

Im currently using datatables with ajax integration. How can I get all the column's data for all the records? My problem is it only gives the current set of data from the table and not all the data. Please see my code below.

```
initComplete: function() {
var customer = table
             .columns(2)
             .data()
             .eq(0)      // Reduce the 2D array into a 1D array of data
             .sort()       // Sort data alphabetically
             .unique()     // Reduce to unique values
             .toArray();

  $.each(customer, function(key, value) {
    $('#customer')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value", value)
         .text(value);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you create working demo code?

Comment: @Swati No. I cannot extract my code from the back-end.